# Best practice for Next.js data fetching inside a component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, apollo-client

I have a menu component that appears globally. What is the best practice for getting data into that component?

I'm trying to take advantage of static generation that Next.js offers but all [data fetching](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching) guidance from the Next.js team relates to pages. `getStaticProps` and `getStaticPaths` seem to pertain to page generation, not data for components. Is their `SWR` package the right answer, or Apollo Client?

Typically in hooks-based React, I'd just put my data call into `useEffect`. I'm not sure how to reason this out being that everything is rendered at build time with Next.

Comment: Are you trying to fetch data BEFORE the page is loaded then push that in to your component (Server Side Rendered), OR are you wanting to have static data that gets sent to the component at build time with Static Generation? If the data that you are wanting to send to your nav component will change, then static generation won't really work here, unless you want to fetch the data with your useEffect after the page has already rendered. If you want the data before the page renders, thus using server side rendering, then there's a way that is possible for that.

Comment: @Chris - it's a pretty simple nav menu, I think static generation would be fine. Just not sure where to make the call.

Comment: As far as I know (still somewhat new to next myself), the only way to get static data is with ```getStaticProps```. Of course this can only be called from individual pages, so it's not possible to add it on the top level layout or specific components. There is one nextjs call that you can use in your custom _app.js, but the call would cause ALL pages to be server side rendered rather than static.

Comment: @Chris - I was looking at doing it through custom `_app` as well, and saw that same thing. It seems like there is a missing data fetching mechanism in the project for global components that need data.

Comment: Yup, given their current documentation that I've read through, the custom _app is the only way to wrap an entire layout. It's definitely unfortunate, and it's what I ended up doing for my most recent application. Hopefully this is something that can be addressed in the future.

Comment: @Chris - you might want to check out `next-with-apollo` - this is the other solution I was eyeing. It's basically doing an HOC pattern on top of `_app.js`. https://github.com/lfades/next-with-apollo#using-_app - I'll post an answer if I get that to work. Thanks for your insight.

Comment: @Chris - I wrote up a big approach to this. Thanks for helping field my initial question, hope my answer returns the favor - and then some. You can get data globally in Next, you just have to do it client side. But that comes with some benefits, read the write up and let me know what you think.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is such a tricky problem, I think we need to lay out some background before a solution comes into focus. I'm focusing in the React.js world but a lot of this would apply to Vue/Nuxt I'd imagine.

### Background / Static Generation Benefits:

Gatsby and Next are focused on generating static pages, which vastly improves performance and SEO in React.js sites. There is a lot of technical overhead to both platforms beyond this simple insight but let's start with this idea of a digital machine pumping out fancy HTML pages for the browser.

### Data Fetching for Pages

In the case of Next.js (as of `v9.5`), their data fetching mechanism [`getStaticProps`](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#getstaticprops-static-generation) does most of the heavy lifting for you but it's sandboxed to the `/pages/` directory. The idea is that it does the data fetching for you and tells the Next.js page generator in Node about it during build time (instead of doing it component-side in a `useEffect` hook - or `componentDidMount`). Gatsby does much the same with their `gatsby-node.js` file, which orchestrates the data fetching for page building in concert with a Node server.

### What about Global Components that need data?

You can use both Gatsby and Next to produce any kind of website but a huge use case are CMS-driven websites, because so much of that content is static. These tools are an ideal fit to that use case.

In typical CMS sites, you will have elements that are global - header, footer, search, menu, etc. This is where static generation faces a big challenge: how do I get data into dynamic global components at build time? The answer to this question is... you don't. And if you think about this for a minute it makes sense. If you had a 10K page site, would you want to trigger a site-wide rebuild if someone adds a new nav item to a menu?

### Data Fetching for Global Components

So how do we get around this? The best answer I have is `apollo-client` and to do the fetch client side. This helps us for a number of reasons:

- For small size queries, the performance impact is negligible.
- If we need to rebuild pages for changes at the CMS layer, this slides by Next/Gatsby's detection mechanisms, so we can make global changes without triggering gigantic site-wide rebuilds.

So what does this actually look like? At the component level, it looks just like a regular Apollo-enhanced component would. I usually use `styled-components` but I tried to strip that out so you can could better see what's going on.

```
import React from 'react'
import { useQuery, gql } from '@apollo/client'
import close from '../public/close.svg'

/**
 * <NavMenu>
 * 
 * Just a typical menu you might see on a CMS-driven site. It takes in a couple of props to move state around.
 * 
 * @param { boolean } menuState - lifted state true/false toggle for menu opening/closing
 * @param { function } handleMenu - lifted state changer for menuState, handles click event
 */

const NAV_MENU_DATA = gql`
  query NavMenu($uid: String!, $lang: String!) {
    nav_menu(uid: $uid, lang: $lang) {
      main_menu_items {
        item {
          ... on Landing_page {
            title
            _linkType
            _meta {
              uid
              id
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
`

const NavMenu = ({ menuState, handleMenu }) => {
  // Query for nav menu from Apollo, this is where you pass in your GraphQL variables
  const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(NAV_MENU_DATA, {
    variables: {
      "uid": "nav-menu",
      "lang": "en-us"
    }
  })
  
  if (loading) return `<p>Loading...</p>`;
  if (error) return `Error! ${error}`;

  // Destructuring the data object
  const { nav_menu: { main_menu_items } } = data

  // `menuState` checks just make sure out menu was turned on
  if (data) return(
    <>
      <section menuState={ menuState }>
        <div>
          { menuState === true && (
            <div>Explore</div>
          )}
          <div onClick={ handleMenu }>
          { menuState === true && (
            <svg src={ close } />
          )}
          </div>
        </div>
        { menuState === true && (
          <ul>
            { data.map( (item) => {
              return (
                <li link={ item }>
                  { item.title }
                </li>
              )
            })}
          </ul>
        )}
      </section>
    </>
  )
}

export default NavMenu
```

### Set Up for Next to Use Apollo

This is actually really well documented by the Next.js team, which makes me feel like I'm not totally hacking the way this tool is supposed to work. You can find [great examples of using Apollo](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples) in their repo.

Steps to get Apollo into a Next app:

1. Make a custom `useApollo` hook that sets up the connection to your data source (I put mine in `/lib/apollo/apolloClient.js` within Next's hierarchy but I'm sure it could go elsewhere).

```
import { useMemo } from 'react'
import { ApolloClient, InMemoryCache, SchemaLink, HttpLink } from '@apollo/client'

let apolloClient

// This is mostly from next.js official repo on how best to integrate Next and Apollo
function createIsomorphLink() {
  // only if you need to do auth
  if (typeof window === 'undefined') {
    // return new SchemaLink({ schema }) 
    return null
  } 
  // This sets up the connection to your endpoint, will vary widely.
  else {
    return new HttpLink({
      uri: `https://yourendpoint.io/graphql`
    })
  }
}

// Function that leverages ApolloClient setup, you could just use this and skip the above function if you aren't doing any authenticated routes
function createApolloClient() {
  return new ApolloClient({
    ssrMode: typeof window === 'undefined',
    link: createIsomorphLink(),
    cache: new InMemoryCache(),
  })
}


export function initializeApollo(initialState = null) {
  const _apolloClient = apolloClient ?? createApolloClient()

  // If your page has Next.js data fetching methods that use Apollo Client, the initial state
  // gets hydrated here
  if (initialState) {
    // Get existing cache, loaded during client side data fetching
    const existingCache = _apolloClient.extract()
    // Restore the cache using the data passed from getStaticProps/getServerSideProps
    // combined with the existing cached data
    _apolloClient.cache.restore({ ...existingCache, ...initialState })
  }
  // For SSG and SSR always create a new Apollo Client
  if (typeof window === 'undefined') return _apolloClient
  // Create the Apollo Client once in the client
  if (!apolloClient) apolloClient = _apolloClient

  return _apolloClient
}

// This is goal, now we have a custom hook we can use to set up Apollo across our app. Make sure to export this!
export function useApollo(initialState) {
  const store = useMemo(() => initializeApollo(initialState), [initialState])
  return store
}
```

2. Modify `_app.js` in the `/pages/` directory of Next. This is basically the wrapper that goes around every page in Next. We're going to add the Apollo provider to this, and now we can globally access Apollo from any component.

```
import { ApolloProvider } from '@apollo/react-hooks'
import { useApollo } from '../lib/apollo/apolloClient'

/**
 * <MyApp>
 * 
 * This is an override of the default _app.js setup Next.js uses
 * 
 * <ApolloProvider> gives components global access to GraphQL data fetched in the components (like menus)
 * 
 */
const MyApp = ({ Component, pageProps }) => {
  // Instantiates Apollo client, reads Next.js props and initialized Apollo with them - this caches data into Apollo.
  const apolloClient = useApollo(pageProps.initialApolloState)

  return (
    <ApolloProvider client={ apolloClient }>
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </ApolloProvider>
  )
}

export default MyApp
```

And now you can get dynamic data inside of your components using Apollo! So easy right ;) HA!

Comment: Why is `SchemaLink` commented out here? It's quite useful.

Comment: What I don't get in your example, is the data in `NavMenu` client-side, SSG or SSR?

Comment: @Mark - all the React components you import into a page in Next follow the generation strategy you set with `getStaticProps` or `getServerProps`. They'll almost always be delivered from the server-side. Apollo fetches the data on client request so it stays fresh

Comment: @Cloud - I wasn't using SchemaLink in my implementation. What would it do for me in this example?

Comment: @serraosays I get it. So with that we can fetch data in a regular component and not in a page component. Because from what I understand is that we cannot use `getStaticProps` in a regular component.

Comment: @Mark - correct. You need this implementation to get data into a non-page component.

Comment: @serraosays Thank you! At the moment I am using another approach/workaround and that is by passing props to components. I am not sure if this is good practice though: https://github.com/markdost/next.js-wp-posts/blob/main/index.example.js

Comment: @Mark - looks kinda cumbersome but should work if I'm following your logic correctly...

Comment: @serraosays You are right about it being a bit to much, I've refactored it in production. I did it this way because it was for a single page website.

Answer (score 1):

For global data fetching in NextJS, I use `react-query` and there is no need for a global state because it lets you to cache the data. Let's say you have a blog with categories and you want to put the category names in the `navbar` as a dropdown menu. In this case you can call the API to fetch the data with `react-query` from the `navbar` component and cache it. The navbar data will be available for all pages.