# Next.JS Static site generation and client-side Apollo fetching

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, next.js, apollo

I'm taking advantage of Next.JS SSG to improve the loading speed of my website. The point is I need some data to be fetched client-side, as it belongs to the user logged-in.

Let's say we have a YouTube-like website, so we would have the `Video page` and a sidebar component, which would be the `VideoRelated`:

I'd generate the `Video page` static, by using the `VideoQuery` at `getStaticProps`. It would also fetch (client-side) the completion status of those for the user logged-in, so it would be something like:

```js
export const VideoRelatedList = ({ videoId, relatedVideos }) => {
  const { data } = useViewerVideoStatusQuery({ variables: { videoId } });
  const relatedVideosViewerStatus = data?.videos;

  const videos = React.useMemo(() => {
    if (!relatedVideosViewerStatus) return relatedVideos;

    return relatedVideos.map((relatedVideo, index) => {
      const viewerHasCompleted = relatedVideosViewerStatus[index]?.id === relatedVideo.id && relatedVideosViewerStatus[index]?.viewerHasCompleted;
      return { ...relatedVideo, viewerHasCompleted };
    });
  }, [relatedVideosViewerStatus, relatedVideos]);

  return (
    <ol>
      {videos.map(({ id, name, viewerHasCompleted }, index) => (
        <li key={id}>
          {name} - {viewerHasCompleted && 'COMPLETED!'}
        </li>
      ))}
    </ol>
  );
};
```

What is the best way to combine both data?

Currently, what I'm doing is combining both by using `React.memo` but I'm not sure if this is a best practice or if there is a better way of achieving what I want.

Comment: Just to better understanding, VideoList is getting related videos as prop. so why there is a query inside this component?

Comment: Because the `relatedVideo` prop would be what the page would pass to the component, which has been static-site generated. But the `useViewerVideoStatusQuery`  is getting the video status related to the user visiting the page, which is obviously logged-in and can't be fetched when building the static-site.

Answer (score 2):

**tl;dr this seems like a fine approach, and you probably don't need `useMemo`**

The Next.js documentation has [a very brief blurb](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#fetching-data-on-the-client-side) on client-side data fetching. It looks, essentially, like what you're doing except that they promote their `swr` library for generic data fetching.

Since you're using GraphQL and Apollo I'm going to operate on the assumption that `useViewerVideoStatusQuery` extends the [`useQuery` hook from `@apollo/client`](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/queries/#executing-a-query).

You mention:

> Currently, what I'm doing is combining both by using React.memo but I'm not sure if this is a best practice or if there is a better way of achieving what I want.

Bear with me, I'm going to try to confirm my understanding of your usecase. If I'm reading correctly, it looks like the `VideoRelatedList` component *can mostly be* fully static, and it looks like that's what you've done - if the extra data hasn't loaded, it just uses the data passed via props that was build via SSG. That's good, and should give you the fastest [First Contentful Paint (FCP)](https://web.dev/fcp/) & [Largest Contentful Paint (LCP)](https://web.dev/lcp/).

Without the additional data, the component would just look like:

```
export const VideoRelatedList = ({ videoId, relatedVideos }) => {
  return (
    <ol>
      {relatedVideos.map(({ id, name, viewerHasCompleted }, index) => (
        <li key={id}>
          {name} - {viewerHasCompleted && 'COMPLETED!'}
        </li>
      ))}
    </ol>
  );
};
```

Now you **additionally** want to incorporate the user data, to provide the feature that tells the user what videos are complete. You are doing this by fetching data after the page has rendered initially with Apollo.

The main change I'd make (unless the `relatedVideos` array is huge or there's some expensive operation I've missed) is to remove `useMemo` as it probably isn't creating significant savings here considering that [performance optimizations aren't free](https://kentcdodds.com/blog/usememo-and-usecallback#whats-the-point).

You might also implementing the `loading` and `error` properties from the `useQuery` hook. That component could look something like:

```js
export const VideoRelatedList = ({ videoId, relatedVideos }) => {
  const { data, loading, error } = useViewerVideoStatusQuery({ variables: { videoId } });

  if (loading) {
    <ol>
      {relatedVideos.map(({ id, name, viewerHasCompleted }, index) => (
        <li key={id}>
          {name} - ...checking status...
        </li>
      ))}
    </ol>
  }

  if (error || !data.videos) {
    return (
      <ol>
        {videos.map(({ id, name, viewerHasCompleted }, index) => (
          <li key={id}>
            {name}
          </li>
        ))}
      </ol>
    );
  }

  const videos = relatedVideos.map((relatedVideo, index) => {
      const viewerHasCompleted = relatedVideosViewerStatus[index]?.id === relatedVideo.id && relatedVideosViewerStatus[index]?.viewerHasCompleted;
      return { ...relatedVideo, viewerHasCompleted };
    });

  return (
    <ol>
      {videos.map(({ id, name, viewerHasCompleted }, index) => (
        <li key={id}>
          {name} - {viewerHasCompleted && 'COMPLETED!'}
        </li>
      ))}
    </ol>
  );
};
```

Again, this is not a huge departure from what you've done besides no `useMemo` and a bit of rearranging. Hopefully it's at least helpful to see another perspective on the topic.

A couple references I found informative on the topic:

- [Advice here regarding the structure to use with `useQuery`](https://github.com/trojanowski/react-apollo-hooks/issues/158#issuecomment-490763073)
- [A more thorough outline of GraphQL/Apollo implementations specifically.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63494479/best-practice-for-next-js-data-fetching-inside-a-component)